# How can I Select records, using a join, that meets two criteria for the same column?

Tags: sql

I have a database with two (actually more) tables: Accounts & Assets. The relationship is many Assets to one Account.

Example of existing data:

```
Account     Asset
Abbot       EZ111
Abbot       7000261
Anderson    EZ431
Barton      EZ207
Barton      8000400
Charlie     8000465
Charlie     EZ576
Dickens     EZ420
Elmer       EZ982
```

I would like to find all Accounts that DO have an Asset that starts with 'EZ', but DO NOT also have an Asset that starts with a '7' or an '8'.

So for the data above, I'd be expecting the result of:

```
Account     Asset
Anderson    EZ431
Dickens     EZ420
Elmer       EZ982
```

Disclaimer: Obviously I don't do SQL for a living, but I'm learning a lot from the W3 site. What I can't figure out is the basic structure of this query. I know how to do the Join, but I don't know how to query the same Column twice.

Sorry if I'm a bit of a newbie for this site, but I mainly use create Groups within InforCRM. A query like this seems to be outside the capabilities of the Group's "Search Criteria" function.

Best Regards,

TimL

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The way you phrased it, I would suggests `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where asset like 'EZ%' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.account = t.account and
                        (t2.asset like '7%' or t2.asset like '8%')
                 );
```

Comment: Wow! First of all thank you for correcting my formatting within like milliseconds after my post. And thank you for the very quick answer as well. I'm going to try it right now and let you know how it worked out! You're amazing!

Comment: Gordon, when you reference "select 1" above, what does the 1 represent? Sorry, once again I am an SQL newbie.

Comment: @TimL . . . The `1` is irrelevant.  `NOT EXISTS` is checking to see if the subquery returns any rows.  I use `1` because it is easy to type.

Answer (score 0):

select * from tablename
where asset like 'EZ%' and account not in (select account from tablename where asset like '7%' or asset like '8%')

Answer (score 0):

Others beat me to it but here is a complete working example based on what I think your data could look like

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8R6CZ36vjZgCUCdqU3DRi/1

```
SELECT ACT.ACCOUNT, AST.ASSET
FROM ACCOUNT ACT
INNER JOIN ASSET AST ON ACT.ACCOUNT = AST.ACCOUNT
WHERE AST.ASSET LIKE 'EZ%' 
    AND ACT.ACCOUNT NOT IN (
      SELECT ACCOUNT FROM ASSET WHERE ASSET LIKE '7%' OR ASSET LIKE '8%'
    );
```